# How to write a function that runs that function on 20 different csv files in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, file, dataframe

I have a directory of 19 csv files each containing a list of student registration numbers and their names. There are two separate files named quiz1 and quiz2 and both these contain information about all students who took these quizzes with their names and total marks obtained. Marks obtained in each have to be segregated into various columns, along with a column 'noofpresent' that shows their attendance for that particular quiz.

My task is parse through all these files and create a dataframe that basically looks like as shown under.[image: sample dataframe with 5 batches instead of 19] The image above shows 5 batches out of a total of 19.

While I have filled up the relevant fields of Batch4, like as shown in the image, I realized repeating that process for 18 files is insane.

How can I write a program or a function that does all the operations for all the remaining 18 remaining batches for both the quizzes? I just need an idea of how to go ahead with the automation logic for the remaining 18 files.

An ex for batch 9 (say):

This is the code I need to replicate for each of the 19 batches:

```
import pandas as pd

spath = 'd:\\a2\\studentlist.csv'
q1path = 'd:\\a2\\quiz\\quiz1.csv'
q2path = 'd:\\a2\\quiz\\quiz2.csv'
b1path = 'd:\\a2\\batchwiselist\\1.csv'
b9path = 'd:\\a2\\batchwiselist\\9.csv'
tpath = 'd:\\a2\\testcasestudent.txt'

# the final dataframe that needs to be created and filled up eventually
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['batch1', 'batch2', 'batch3', 'batch4', 'batch9'], ['quiz1', 'quiz2']])
cols=['noofpresent', 'lesserthan50', 'between50and60', 'between60and70', 'between70and80', 'greaterthan80']
statdf = pd.DataFrame('-', idx, cols)


# ============BATCH 9===================]

# ----------- QUIZ 1 -----------]

# Master list of students in Batch 9
b9 = pd.read_csv(b9path, usecols=['studentName', 'admissionNumber'])
b9.rename(columns={'studentName' : 'Firstname'}, inplace=True)
# To match column from quiz1.csv to batch9.csv to for merger

# Master list of all who attended Quiz1
q1 = pd.read_csv(q1path, usecols = ['Firstname', 'Grade/10.00', 'State'], na_values = ['-', 'In progress', np.NaN])
q1.dropna(inplace=True)
q1['Grade/10.00'] = q1['Grade/10.00'] * 10
# Multiplying the grades by 10 to mark against 100 instead of 10

# Merge batch9 list of names to list of quiz1 on their firstname column
q1b9 = pd.merge(b9, q1)
q1b9 = q1.loc[q1['Firstname'].isin(b9.Firstname)]        # checking if the name exits in either lists
q1b9.reset_index(inplace=True)
#print(q1b9)

lt50 = q1b9.loc[(q1b9['Grade/10.00'] < 50)]         
#findout list of students whose grades are lesser than 50
out9q1 = (lt50['Grade/10.00'].count())
# print(out9q1) to just get the count of number of students who got <50 quiz1 from batch9

# Similar process for quiz2 below for batch9.
# -------------------- QUIZ 2 ------------------]

# Master list of all who attended Quiz2
q2 = pd.read_csv(q2path, usecols = ['Firstname', 'Grade/10.00', 'State'], na_values = ['-', 'In progress', np.NaN])
q2.dropna(inplace=True)
q2['Grade/10.00'] = q2['Grade/10.00'] * 10

# Merge B1 to Q2
q2b9 = pd.merge(b9, q2)
q2b9 = q2.loc[q2['Firstname'].isin(b9.Firstname)]
q2b9.reset_index(inplace=True)


q2b9.loc[(q2b9['Grade/10.00'] <= 50)].count()
lt50 = q2b9.loc[(q2b9['Grade/10.00'] < 50)]
out9q2 = (lt50['Grade/10.00'].count())
# print(out9q2)
```

The above code computes for all students who obtained less than 50 in either quizzes. I have done similar for batch4. I need to replicate this so that one function can do so for all the available remaining (17-18)batches.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: I have added some code for your reference.

Comment: Assuming that all the files can be handled by one function that does all the things, then just make a list of the files, for each of them, invoke that function. Presumably, that function would return your corrected data frame, which you can then concatenate and do other things with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the below code I have generated all csv paths and loads one by one then do all the process then resulted dataframes are saved in a list of  dataframes like [[batch1_q1_result, batch1_q2_result], [batch2_q1_result, batch2_q2_result] ...]

```
def doAll(baseBatchPath, numberOfBatches):
    batchResultListAll = [] # this will store the resulted dataframes
    spath = 'd:\\a2\\studentlist.csv'
    q1path = 'd:\\a2\\quiz\\quiz1.csv'
    q2path = 'd:\\a2\\quiz\\quiz2.csv'
    tpath = 'd:\\a2\\testcasestudent.txt'
    # the final dataframe that needs to be created and filled up eventually
    idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['batch1', 'batch2', 'batch3', 'batch4', 'batch9'], ['quiz1', 'quiz2']])
    cols=['noofpresent', 'lesserthan50', 'between50and60', 'between60and70', 'between70and80', 'greaterthan80']
    statdf = pd.DataFrame('-', idx, cols)

    # Master list of all who attended Quiz1
    q1 = pd.read_csv(q1path, usecols = ['Firstname', 'Grade/10.00', 'State'], na_values = ['-', 'In progress', np.NaN])
    q1.dropna(inplace=True)
    q1['Grade/10.00'] = q1['Grade/10.00'] * 10
    # Master list of all who attended Quiz2
    q2 = pd.read_csv(q2path, usecols = ['Firstname', 'Grade/10.00', 'State'], na_values = ['-', 'In progress', np.NaN])
    q2.dropna(inplace=True)
    q2['Grade/10.00'] = q2['Grade/10.00'] * 10

    # generate each batch file path and do other works
    for batchId in range(numberOfBatches-1):
        batchCsvPath = baseBatchPath + str(batchId+1) + ".csv"
        # Master list of students in Batch 9
        batch = pd.read_csv(batchCsvPath, usecols=['studentName', 'admissionNumber'])
        batch.rename(columns={'studentName' : 'Firstname'}, inplace=True)
        # Merge eachBatch list of names to list of quiz1 on their firstname column
        q1batch = pd.merge(batch, q1)
        q1batch = q1.loc[q1['Firstname'].isin(batch.Firstname)]        # checking if the name exits in either lists
        q1batch.reset_index(inplace=True)
        #print(q1batch)

        lt50 = q1batch.loc[(q1batch['Grade/10.00'] < 50)]         
        #findout list of students whose grades are lesser than 50
        outBatchq1 = (lt50['Grade/10.00'].count())
        # print(outBatchq1) to just get the count of number of students who got <50 quiz1 from batch -> batchId

        #do same for quiz 2

        # Merge each Batch to Q2
        q2batch = pd.merge(batch, q2)
        q2batch = q2.loc[q2['Firstname'].isin(batch.Firstname)]
        q2batch.reset_index(inplace=True)


        q2batch.loc[(q2batch['Grade/10.00'] <= 50)].count()
        lt50 = q2batch.loc[(q2batch['Grade/10.00'] < 50)]
        outBatchq2 = (lt50['Grade/10.00'].count())
        # print(outBatchq2)
        # finally save the resulted DF for later use
        batchResultListAll.append([q1batch, q2batch])


#call the function using base path and number of batch csv files        
doAll("d:\\\\a2\\\\batchwiselist\\\\", 18)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a list object which contains all the CSV file paths and then use a for loop to parse through all this. Obviously you will have to tweak your code where you have hard coded in the csv file with the now dynamic `file`
Something like this:

```
csv_files = ['file1.csv','file2.csv2']
for file in csv_files:
      (YOUR CODE GOES HERE)
```